# Duplicate history of multiline text box in infopath

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

in a sharepoint form i have a multiline textbox that allow to "append changes to existing text".

The problem is that everytime i edit the text in the control and i submit the form, infopath duplicate the history. So it's like i ve inserted twice that text. This happen first time too.

I could notice that the problem do not persist if I use the default insert form instead of the infopath form.
So i suppose the problem is on submit and not in visualization.

Following an attached image:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLlRh.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DO not exist history at column level. It exists just at list level even if it appears like the history can be also at column level.

So, it was duplicate because i did twice the submit of the list.